# Android Opengl: Alternate values for gl_FragColor

Tags: opengl, android, opengl-es

I'm writing an Android application that utilizes opengl to perform some changes to the camera output.  I've written my code in such a way that I finally figured out what is causing the performance issue.

```
#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
precision mediump float;
uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;
uniform vec4 vColor;
const int MAX_COLORS = 6;
uniform float vHues[MAX_COLORS];
uniform float vOffsets[MAX_COLORS];
varying vec2 v_CamTexCoordinate;

float rgb2hue(vec4 c) {
    vec4 K = vec4(0.0, -1.0 / 3.0, 2.0 / 3.0, -1.0);
    vec4 p = mix(vec4(c.bg, K.wz), vec4(c.gb, K.xy), step(c.b, c.g));
    vec4 q = mix(vec4(p.xyw, c.r), vec4(c.r, p.yzx), step(p.x, c.r));

    float d = q.x - min(q.w, q.y);
    float e = 1.0e-10;
    return abs(q.z + (q.w - q.y) / (6.0 * d + e));
}

bool isInRange(float a1,float a2, float vOffset) {
    if(a2 < 0.0) {
        return false;
    } else if(abs(a1-a2) < vOffset) {
        return true;
    } else if( a1 > a2) {
        return (1.0 - a1 + a2) < vOffset;
    } else {
        return (1.0 + a1 - a2) < vOffset;
    }
}

vec4 getGrey(vec4 c) {
    float grey = (c.r + c.g + c.b) / 3.0;
    return vec4(grey, grey, grey, c.a);
}

void main() {
    vec4 c = texture2D(sTexture, v_CamTexCoordinate);
    bool hasColor = vHues[0] >= 0.0;
    float hue = rgb2hue(c);
    vec4 test = getGrey(c);
    for(int i=0; i < MAX_COLORS; i++) {
       if(isInRange(hue, vHues[i], vOffsets[i])) {
          //If I uncomment this line the performance gets terrible
          //test = c;
       }
    }
    gl_FragColor = test;
}
```

There is a significant hit to performance (a lot of frames are skipped) when I uncomment the line above.  I basically want to use the original color sometimes and a different color depending on some condition.  It works but is there a more efficient way to do this?  Also, why does this perform so poorly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if  the line is commented, the compiler can most likely optimize out the loop, which is why the shader runs faster then.

You have a lot of branches (`if`/`else`) in your shader, which is most likely your performance issue. Branching (especially on mobile devices) is something you generally want to avoid.

If your uniforms (hue and offsets) do not change very often, you might consider hardcoding them into the shader (i.e. regenerate the shader whenever they change).

I am not sure about the `rgb2hue` method, but it looks rather vectorized, which is why it might perform fast enough.

Your `isInRange` however is full of branches, which will most likely be the performance bottleneck.

You might want to consider generating a 3D-LUT on the CPU side, and then sample that in your shader. That will most likely be faster than evaluating all those branches.

Comment: How would I go about doing the 3D-LUT?  I think you are right about the condition statements so I'd like to give that a try.

Comment: Basically you generate a 3D Texture of the resolution 64x64x64 or so. Then for every pixel in the LUT, you perform that pixel shader, using color = (x, y, z) as input (whereas x,y,z are the coordinates in the LUT).

To lookup the LUT, you can simply do texture2D(myLut, color).rgb;

Comment: Sorry for being such a opengl noob but can you point me to a relevant example of this?  I'm having a hard time learning this stuff on line.  The only 3D lut examples I'm seeing are referring to bitmaps.

Comment: http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter24.html This is probably exactly what you want

Comment: Thank you very much.  I ended up creating a lut and passing it in as a uniform float[] and the performance is so much better.  That link really helped my understand this strategy!

Comment: You will probably get even better performance if you use a texture instead of a float array, but if the performance is already good enough, no need to worry about